# Confusion about dependent function type

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, type-theory

Here's how dependent functions are introduced, according to the HoTT book:

> To define $f: \prod_{x:A} B(x)$, where $f$ is the name of a dependent
> function to be defined, we need an expression $\Phi: B(x)$ possibly
> involving the variable $x: A $ and we write $$f(x):\equiv \Phi \text{
>  for } x: A.$$

Now I'm looking at https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Formal+Semantics+in+Modern+Type+Theories-p-9781119489214 (pages 35-36):

> [...] CN is the universe of all (interpretations of) common nouns. As
> such, CN is the type whose objects include, for example, $Man$ that
> interprets ‘man’, $\Sigma x:Table.red(x)$ that interprets “red table”,
> and many other types that interpret common nouns. [...]
>
> $some : \Pi A : CN. (A \to Prop) \to Prop$
>
> [...]
>
> we can interpret the sentence (2.23) as (2.24), where $Student : CN$
> and $speak : Human → Prop$ (and $Student$ is a subtype of $Human$):
>
> (2.23) Some students spoke.
>
> (2.24) $some(Student, speak)$

In this setting, $some$ appears to be the name of a dependent function to be defined, as in the first quote above. But now I'm a bit confused because the authors do not define $some(x)$, i.e., they don't say which expression $\Phi$ $some(x)$ should be equal to. And they also don't say what $some(x)(y)$ should be equal to. We only know that $some(student)(speak)$ is well-typed, but it's not said which expression it should be equal to. Or is "$some(student)(speak)$" considered to be an expression itself?

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\some}{some}\DeclareMathOperator{\Prop}{Prop}$$\some : \prod_{A : CN}{(A \to \Prop) \to \Prop}$ might be defined by $\some(A)(P) = \exists_{a : A}{P(a)}$. For the quoted passage, I don't really think having a formal expression for $\some$ is the point, just that there *is* some expression that works and that you can use it to interpret sentences. Similarly for $speak$ and $Student$.

Comment: OK, so it's parallel to the model theory, where e.g. a function symbol $f$ is interpreted as some function $f^M$. But in MT, what $f^M$ is exactly depends on the model $M$. In type theory, we don't have any models. Then how do we know what function exactly we are dealing with? Your definition of $some$ makes sense (because "some" is a "logical constant"), but what if we had something like $small: \Pi_{A:CN} A\to Prop$? We only know that $small(A)$ has type $Prop$ but we don't know what function exactly $small$ is. I guess I don't get the type-theoretic "philosophy" more generally.

Comment: @user1108335 I don't mean that the choice of $\mathrm{some}$ doesn't matter in general, but more that it doesn't matter for what the passage is doing (i.e. exposition). I was able to come up with a definition for $\mathrm{some}$ by using my intuition for what it should be (and its type), and you might be able to do the same for $\mathrm{small}$. If you want to be formal, then you'd certainly want to go ahead and be more explicit.